# Integer part of a sum (floor)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $\left(\, x_{n}\,\right)_{\,n\ \geq\ 1}$ be a sequence defined as follows:
$$
x_{1}={1 \over 2014}\quad\mbox{and}\quad x_{n + 1}=x_{n} + x_{n}^{2}\,,
\qquad\forall\ n\ \geq\ 1
$$
Compute the integer part of the sum:
$$
S=\frac{x_1}{x_2} + \frac{x_2}{x_3} + \cdots +\frac{x_{2014}}{x_{2015}}\,,\qquad
\left(\,\mbox{i. e.}\  \left\lfloor\, S\,\right\rfloor\,\right)$$

Any nice idea to approach this? How can one find a formula for $x_{n}$?
Thank you!

Comment: Recurrence relations aren't solvable in general. Are you sure that there is a solution?

Comment: It is clearly that not all recurrences have a closed form. This is from a youth magazine.

Comment: Alright, so there should be an answer, thanks. And yes, I meant a closed form solution in terms of $n$.

Comment: You are welcome! Maybe there is a mistske, but I'm interested in solving the problem as it is! At first sight I thought it is easy, but I have never been so wrong.

Comment: Deceptively simple, isn't it? I've taken a few stabs at it, but nothing seems to be working. Unfortunately, I have to get back to studying for my exams.

Comment: Yes, simple but complicated. I wish you good luck with your exams!

Comment: @CFG: What exact magazine is this? Did you change any part of the problem? Are calculators allowed or is a mathematical proof required?

Comment: A mathematical proof is required. I think there is something wrong with the problem, but I like it!

Comment: @CFG: Please don't deface the posts like that.

Comment: It was one of my friends who did this. I appologize!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get a bound on $\dfrac{1}{x_{2015}}$, let $y_n = \dfrac{1}{x_n}$. Then, $\dfrac{1}{y_{n+1}} = \dfrac{1}{y_n}+\dfrac{1}{y_n^2} = \dfrac{y_n+1}{y_n^2}$.

Hence, $y_{n+1} = \dfrac{y_n^2}{y_n+1} = y_n-\dfrac{y_n}{y_n+1}$. Rearrange to get $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{y_n}\right)(y_n-y_{n+1}) = 1$.

Since $y_n$ is a decreasing sequence and $1+\dfrac{1}{y}$ is a decreasing function, we have:

$2014 = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 1}^{2014}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{y_n}\right)(y_n-y_{n+1}) = \sum_{n = 1}^{2014}\int_{y_{n+1}}^{y_n}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{y_n}\right)\,dy \le \sum_{n = 1}^{2014}\int_{y_{n+1}}^{y_n}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{y}\right)\,dy = \int_{y_{2015}}^{y_1}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{y}\right)\,dy = \left[y + \ln y\right]_{y_{2015}}^{y_1} = (2014+\ln 2014)-(y_{2015}+\ln y_{2015})$

Therefore, $y_{2015}+\ln y_{2015} \le \ln 2014$. Exponentiation yields $y_{2015}e^{y_{2015}} \le 2014$.

If you can convince yourself that $6e^6 > 2014$, then we have $y_{2015} \le 6$ (because $ye^y$ is increasing).

Therefore, $S = 2014 - y_{2015} \ge 2008$. It remains to show that $S \le 2009$, i.e. $y_{2015} \ge 5$.

Answer (score 17):

Your sum is telescoping since

$$S={\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac{x_{k}}{x_{k+1}}=\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac{x_{k}^{2}}{x_{k}x_{k+1}}=\sum_{k=1}^{2014}\frac{x_{k+1}-x_{k}}{x_{k}x_{k+1}}=\sum_{k=1}^{2014}(\frac{1}{x_{k}}-\frac{1}{x_{k+1}})}
$$
$$
{\displaystyle =\frac{1}{x_{1}}-\frac{1}{x_{2015}}=2014-\frac{1}{x_{2015}}.}$$

Hence it's a matter of evaluating $x_{2015}$. 
It seems that $.17<x_{2015}<.18$ and $S=2008.22$.

Some identities that might help
$$ x_{2015}=x_1+\sum_{k=1}^{2014} x_k^2;\ x_{2015}=x_1(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(1+x_{2014})$$probably with some inequalities involving sums and products.

Comment: I knew that the sum is telescoping. My problem is with $x_{2015}$. How do you get that inequality, @Silencer?

Comment: I made mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Look also [here](http://pastebin.com/RMtxWNnV). You can take bigger precision, and (if I didn't make mistake) receive the answer should be 2008.

Comment: @CFG Would you be so kind and edit your problem so that it reflects the things you knew like the fact that the sum is telescoping and that it reduces to $x_{2015}$?

Comment: @Silencer If the answer 2008 is correct then it makes the mathematical proof of this problem even more interesting!

Comment: @NeutralElement it looks like it is. Everything seems correct. But I don't have idea, how to prove it using pen and paper.

Answer (score 5):

JimmyK has ignored the request (in now deleted comments) to add the lower bound proof to his answer, so I will add an answer with the lower bound proof which will resolve the question completely.

Just like Jimmy's excellent upper bound proof we use

$$ 2014 = \sum_{n=1}^{2014}\left(1 + \frac{1}{y_n}\right)(y_n - y_{n+1}) = \sum_{n=1}^{2014} \int_{y_{n+1}}^{y_n} \left(1 + \frac{1}{y_n}\right) dy$$

Now we can easily show by induction that $y_k \gt -1$ and thus

$$y_{n+1} + 1 \gt y_{n+1} + \frac{y_n}{1+y_n} = y_n$$

Thus we have that

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{y_n}\right) \ge \left(1 + \frac{1}{y_{n+1} +1}\right)$$

Now for $-1 \lt y_{n+1} \le y$ we have that

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{y_{n+1} +1}\right) \ge \left(1 + \frac{1}{y +1}\right)$$

Thus
$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{y_n}\right) \ge \left(1 + \frac{1}{y +1}\right)$$

Let $a = y_{2015}$

We thus have

$$ 2014 = \sum_{n=1}^{2014} \int_{y_{n+1}}^{y_n} \left(1 + \frac{1}{y_n}\right)dy \ge \sum_{n=1}^{2014} \int_{y_{n+1}}^{y_n} \left(1 + \frac{1}{y +1}\right) dy = \int_{a}^{2014} \left(1 + \frac{1}{y +1}\right) dy =$$
$$ 2014-a + \log(2015) - \log(a+1)$$

Thus

$$ 2014 \ge 2014-a + \log(2015) - \log(a+1)$$

which means

$$ a + \log(a+1) \ge \log (2015)$$

giving us

$$ (a+1)e^{a} \ge 2015$$

Now $6e^5 \lt 6 \times3^5 = 1458$ and since $(x+1)e^x$ is increasing, we have $$a \gt 5$$

This coupled with the other two answers gives the answer of $$2008$$

---

An observation:

$$y_{n+1} = y_n - \frac{f(y_n)}{f'(y_n)}$$

where  $f(y) = ye^y$.

This is a Newton Raphson recurrence and techniques used there should be applicable here.

Comment: @CFG: You are welcome. Can you please tell us the name of the youth magazine? Sounds like a very interesting one...

Comment: @CFG: Thanks...!

Comment: Interesting. CFG deleted his comment. The magazine is apparently Gazetta Mathematica. I was unable to find it in there though (didn't look too hard).

Comment: Please delete your comment. It's from an additional collection of this magazine (for fun), which can't be found on the internet.

Comment: @CFG: I don't understand. What is wrong with mentioning the source? Someone who has physical access can take a look.